# ADF selectOneChoice triggers ValueChangeListener alternately

Tags: jsp, oracle-adf

I have a SelectOneChoice that holds a list of SelectItems that I populate thru a ManagedBean. That SOC have a ValueChangeListener that trigger some actions in a BackingBean.
The problem is that sometimes the ValueChangeListener is been triggered, and sometimes not. More on, When the ValueChangeListener return to work, sometimes it's not sending the correct data to the listener.

Using JDev 11g R1 (11.1.1.7.0).

my SelectOneChoice:

```
<af:selectOneChoice label="Change budget code" id="socChangeBudgetCode"
   valueChangeListener="#{backingBeanScope.BudgetBean.changeBudgetCode}" 
   autoSubmit="true"
   disabled="#{NewBudgetBean.itemCount &lt;= 1}"
   value="#{bindings.budgetNum.inputValue}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{NewBudgetBean.items}" id="si1"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

my ValueChangeListener:

```
public void changeBudgetCode(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
   System.out.println("BudgetBean.changeBudgetCode(); old = " + vce.getOldValue() + "; new = " + vce.getNewValue());
   budgetNum = (String)vce.getNewValue(); // budgetNum is a member in BudgetBean
   callBudjectDetailsWS(); // callBudjectDetailsWS uses the value in budgetNum and call a webservice to do some work
}
```

Comment: Need jdev version and how you know for sure it’s not being called.

Comment: We are using JDev 11g R1 (11.1.1.7.0).
I print to the soa log file in my ValueChangeListener, and the callBudjectDetailsWS() is calling a webservice in our OSB that report on every call it receive.

Comment: I would test to make sure that the called VCL method is printing to the WLS console each time - if it is not - I would log an SR. If it is, then next check if OSB is receiving every call - if not Log an SR. The issue needs to be reproducible. Also, try testing in a different project to see if the VCL fires consistently - if it does then something is wrong in your current project. Also, 11.1.1.7.0 is 5 releases back on current production.

Comment: My eyes may be wrong, but how does this even compile? callBudjectDetailsWS())  isn't there an extra right )?  And you know if you select the same item twice then a new VCL event is *not* thrown, right? Only for an actual change in value (old and new are different)  and it's misspelled.

Comment: The extra parentheses is a typo. and yes, I know that if the current item is been selected again, my VCL will not be fired.